# Find an Angle of a Right Triangle Without Trigonometric Functions

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, triangles

I have a right triangle triangle. I know the length of the hypotenuse (H) and one adjacent side (A). I would like to find the angle between the A and the H without using $\arccos(A/H)$. I would like to avoid all trigonometric equations. Is there a theorem or method to find this angle without using trig?

Here is the general problem I am trying to solve:
[image]

I am unable to factor the acos() function to isolate H. Perhaps this is due to my limited experience with math. If so, is there a resource I should look into or another way to solve the problem

Comment: If your goal is to avoid using the trigonometric functions, it may be worth evaluating your ultimate goal to see whether you actually need to know the _angle_ at all.  For practical applications, much of what you might want to do (for instance, projecting one vector down to another, or reflecting a vector about another one) can be done by vector operations without ever needing to know any of the angles specifically.

Comment: as a related question, how can I add $2+3$ without using math?

Comment: @StevenStadnicki Thanks for the response. I added more to the description about how I am applying this.

Comment: Is D in your description the angle the wheel has rotated, or the distance the center has moved?  From context I'm presuming the former, but that's a curious measure to have available.  Where does the problem come from?

Comment: @StevenStadnicki In some ways it is both. It is the distance the center has moved. However, D can be described in terms of radians. Note that the arc (D) has a constant radius which is equal to the radius of the wheel. I am applying this to robots.

Comment: @noah if it's the arc distance moved, then you're right (and that makes a lot of sense); if it's linear distance then that's another matter entirely (and also straightforwardly solvable).

Comment: @StevenStadnicki It is the arc distance moved. I have considered using linear distance but that is not a precise measure of axle distance moved. The step acts as a fulcrum & the wheel rotates around it.

Comment: @Noah The reason I mention it is that if you have the linear distance between the two points (the center when contacting the step, and the center when on the edge of the step) in your configuration you can figure out the height $H$ without needing to do any trig specifically, just a little pythagorean geometry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can avoid using the trigonometric functions, by using tables of known values or some approximation of them (series expansions, solving certain algebraic equations for some cases etc.).

But in a sense you use them indirectly. It might help if you give some more background. Like you code some game in assembler and have no math library available.

**Update:**

We have the arc length $D = R \varphi$ and thus
$$
D = R \arccos\left(\frac{R-H}{R}\right)
$$
We can invert $D(H)$ to $H(D)$ by
$$
H = R\left(1-\cos\left(\frac{D}{R}\right)\right)
$$
Here is a plot for $x = D/R = 1 + \delta$ $H(x)$ and two approximations:
[image]

Comment: Thanks for the response. Please see my updated description for more background.

Comment: @Noah Is this working for you? Using a cosine function should be no problem by itself, I understood you just had troubles with the calculation of the inverse function and that is why you wanted to avoid the trigonometric functions.

Comment: This is a big help. Is there a resource you recommend for learning more about factoring trig functions like this?

Comment: @Noah What do you mean by factoring? I used two techniques: One is transforming both sides of an equation simultaneously (using equivalent transformations) to reach an equation for the inverse function. (This is teached in school, around 7th-8th grade). The other is the taylor expansion of a function. (This is teached in school in the last classes, probably if you have math as topic, or in the first course on calculus at university). Wikipedia usually gives a nice introduction and references.

Comment: After looking those methods up, I was able to understand how you came up with that solution. Thanks again for the help!

Answer (score 3):

Except for special cases like the 30-60-90 and 45-45-90 triangles, finding angles from the sides in finitely many steps is a *definition* of trigonometric equations. So no, you can't do it in general.

If you allow infinite series or their approximations, you could do it--but basically you would be using calculus combined with trigonometry. Or you could use the trig ratios for a few angles and combine them. Those two methods are how computers and calculators do trigonometric ratios.